# Android - How to use transactions when modifying database via ContentProvider?

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions, android-contentprovider, android-database

When a user taps their NFC tag, my app:

1. Inserts a new user into the `users` table, getting back the user `_id`, then
2. Writes this `_id` value to the user's NFC tag.

The problem is that if that user moves their tag away too quickly, step 2 will fail with an `IOException`. The user will then have to tap their tag again, but this will result in step 1 being repeated - i.e., duplicate entries. :-/

To overcome this issue, I would like to use transactions based on [this example code from the API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()):

```
   db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     // Insert data into database, getting back _id
     // Write _id to NFC tag
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

...but my database is wrapped in a `MyContentProvider`, so I don't have access to `db`.

Is there a way to use transactions when inserting data without abandoning the usage of the `MyContentProvider`?

Comment: do not use autogenerated _id ... use somthing different like guid

Comment: Thanks. If the desired solution isn't possible. I will consider that. (Deleting the inserted row is also an option, but obviously far from ideal).

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse the operations: you could query your database for the next available ID, write the ID to the NFC tag, then update the database with that ID if you were successful in updating the NFC tag.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but (how) is it possible to get the next available ID via a content provider?

Comment: You can query your content provider by ID, and sort by descending order.
contentProvider.query(uri, new String[] {"_id"}, null, null, "_id DESC");
Get the first entry in your cursor and then increase the ID by one. You can use a LIMIT on your query as well to pull only 1 entry.